# VB control loaded using in .Net Winform Application

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I have hosted a COM activex control in .net Winform application using AxHost implementation , now COM activex ocx control is implemented in  Visual Basics .Now Vb code implements few COM interfaces,interface IABC is one of them.

my VB code looks like:

```
implements IABC

public void YYYYY()
End Sub

public void ZZZZZ()
End Sub
```

Now in C# code

```
public class AxHostControl:AxHost
{
  public AxHostControl(string guid):base(guid)
  {
  }
}
```

In C# WinformUI Application

```
var m_axHost = new AxHostControl(ocx_guid);
this.Controls.Add(m_axHost);
```

Then, I tried to get the Ocx as

```
var ocxObject =m_axHost.GetOcx();
var abcControl = (IABC)ocxObject;
```

In between I call `abcControl.YYYYY();` or `abcControl.ZZZZZ();`

Now my question is that as `abcControl` is `ComObject` , if I dispose the `m_axHost` using `m_axHost.dispose();` the ocx control will be unloaded from the UI but how to dispose the COM object `abcControl` from C# otherwise there will be a memory leak?